# A computation expression to get the first valid result out, in F#

Tags: f#

How can I achieve something like this in a clean way?

let's imagine this simple code:

```
let a () = checkSomeStuff ();     None
let b () = do Something ();       Some "thing"
let c () = checkSomethingElse (); None


"getOne" {
    do! a()
    do! b()
    do! c()
}
```

and it would return the first "Some".

I could achieve this exact behavior by using Result where I'd return the value through an Error and continue through with Ok, but that is not readable / nice:

```
let a () = checkSomeStuff ();     Ok ()
let b () = do Something ();       Error "thing"
let c () = checkSomethingElse (); Ok ()


result {
    do! a()
    do! b()
    do! c()
}
```

this would work, but I'm looking to achieve that without mis-using the Result type. Can it be done with the existing expressions?

Comment: With expressions existing where?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, either finding some clever use of existing Option, etc or in the common libs like FSToolkit or FSharpPlus. Since this is for a small piece of code, my question is more to see if I missed an obvious way to do this simply vs. rolling a new expression that will end up being of similar size than the code itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function that does what you want. But you have to think throughout what you want to do.

So, your logic is.

1. You execute a function that returns an `option`
2. Then you check that `option`. if it is `None` you execute another function, if it is `Some` you return the value.

A function like these could look like this:

```ml
let getSome f opt =
    match opt with
    | None   -> f ()
    | Some x -> Some x
```

With such a function, you then could write. ***

```
let x =
    checkSomeStuff ()
    |> getSome (fun _ -> Something () )
    |> getSome checkSomethingElse
```

But then i think, hmmm.... isn't there a better name for `getSome`? In some way i want to say:

> Execute some code and check if it is `Some`, **or else** pick the next thing.

With this in mind, i think. hmm.... isn't there already a `Option.orElse`? And yes! There is! There is also a `Option.orElseWith` function, that fits your need even better. So now, you can write.

```
let y =
    checkSomeStuff ()
    |> Option.orElseWith (fun _ -> Something () )
    |> Option.orElseWith checkSomethingElse
```

If you have functions with side-effects, then you should use `Option.orElseWith`, otherwise, you can just sue `Option.orElse`

---

***: I assume you have the following function defined

```
let checkSomeStuff () =
    None

let Something () =
    Some "thing"

let checkSomethingElse () =
    None
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a computation expression for this. F# has a built-in function called [`Seq.tryPick`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#tryPick) that applies a given function to successive elements of a sequence, returning the first `Some` result, if any. You can use `tryPick` to define `getOne` like this:

```ml
let getOne fs =
    fs |> Seq.tryPick (fun f -> f ())
```

Trying it with your example:

```ml
let a () = checkSomeStuff ();
let b () = Something ();
let c () = checkSomethingElse ();

let x = getOne [ a; b; c ]
printfn "%A" x   // Some "thing"
```

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, I wrote a post about [imperative computation expression builder](http://tomasp.net/blog/imperative-i-return.aspx/) that does something along those lines. You can represent computations as option-returning functions:

```
type Imperative<'T> = unit -> option<'T>
```

In the computation builder, the main thing is the `Combine` operation that represents sequencing of operations, but you need a few others to make it work:

```
type ImperativeBuilder() = 
  member x.ReturnFrom(v) = v
  member x.Return(v) = (fun () -> Some(v))
  member x.Zero() = (fun () -> None)
  member x.Delay(f:unit -> Imperative<_>) = 
    (fun () -> f()())
  member x.Combine(a, b) = (fun () ->
    match a() with 
    | Some(v) -> Some(v) 
    | _ -> b() )

let imperative = new ImperativeBuilder()
```

You can then reimplement your example - to return a value, you just use `return`, but you need to combine individual operations using `return!`, because the builder does not support `do!`:

```
let a () = imperative { printfn "one" }
let b () : Imperative<string> = imperative { return "result" }
let c () = imperative { printfn "two" }

let f = imperative {
    return! a()
    return! b()
    return! c()
}

f()
```